# Super Secret Settings help in 1.8.8

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In the new snapshot of Minecraft (13w36b) there is a button in the options menu labeled "Super Secret Settings". When I clicked this button, an Enderman-ish sound played. Does it do anything or is it just a sound?

Comment: but that doesint work in 1.8.8

Comment: 13w36b is neither 1.8.8, nor is it a "new snapshot". It's been out for about 2 years, minus 3 weeks, making it a snapshot for 1.6.4 or 1.7. The actual new snapshots for 1.9 don't have that button any more. Meaning your question doesn't actually make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The sound that plays is just a teaser. Basically aesthetic.

The reset to normal you can either continue clicking on the button which will eventually cycle back to the original shader. If you do not wish to wait you can also press F4 to reset it.

The wiki states that this feature has been discontinued and removed in the more recent snapshot and will not be in version 1.9

Answer (score 0):

The Super Secret Settings button will play a random sound when clicked, but it will also **switch between different shaders** that affect the way you view the game.

Information about this can be found on the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Shaders).